# Do M1 Macs work as sources for Target Display Mode on a 2011 iMac?

Tags: imac, apple-silicon, compatibility, target-display

I realise that similar questions have been asked in the past, but I don’t think this is a duplicate.

I have a 2011 iMac that I use as an external monitor for my laptop. I’d like to know if this would still work if I upgrade the laptop.

According to [Apple’s website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592).

> The other Mac that you're connecting it to must have been introduced in 2019 or earlier and have macOS Catalina or earlier installed.

This is definitely not precisely accurate, as I currently use it with a 2013 MBP with Big Sur. I suppose that is now unsupported and could potentially stop working with a software update -  that will certainly be a risk with a newer system. Reading other answers here it appears that some newer models work similarly.

It seems that the new M1 machines being more radically different, I would not necessarily expect it to work if I were to replace my current laptop with one of those (plugged in via a USB-C adapter), but I haven’t been able to find any specific accounts of this.

Comment: I have a mid-2011 27" iMac with High Sierra and a 2019 MBP running on Big Sur v11.6.1. The target display mode does not work. It used to when the MBP was running on Catalina. I have read many comments / complaints from people running Big Sur about target display mode. Happy to hear that yours is working. What is the exact version of Big Sur you have installed on your laptop?

Comment: @Alper: How did you connect the two Macs  together. One has thunderbolt and the other has thunderbolt3.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I used a [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) and an [Apple Thunderbolt Cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m) but now they are both useless to me!

Comment: @Alper I'm not at that machine right now, but it's been working with various versions of Big Sur - once I'd taken the plunge to update from Catalina I keep installing updates as they come. The system does have an NVidia GPU - I suppose that could be relevant.